# On a proof of the Big Picard Theorem using covering spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, covering-spaces, modular-function

I'm studying the paper *The Big Picard Theorem and Other Results on Riemann Surfaces* by P. Arés-Gastesi and T. Venkataramana, which presents a new proof of the Big Picard Theorem using covering spaces rather than the classical one which uses Montel's Theorem. The theorem, as stated in the paper is

**Theorem 3.2.** If $f:\mathbb{D}^*\to X=\hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus\{\infty,0,1\}$ is holomorphic then $f$ cannot have an essential singularity at the origin.

(Where $\mathbb{D}^*=\{z\in\mathbb{C}; 0<|z|<1\}$ and $\hat{\mathbb{C}}\cong\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ is the Riemann Sphere)

I'm having trouble to understand the beginning of the proof, which I quote below:

> Let $c$ be a generator of the fundamental group of $\mathbb{D}^*$ (we again make an abuse of notation and use the same letter for a path and its homology class) and let $\gamma$ be the element of $\Gamma(2)$ [the [principal congruence subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup#principal_congruence_subgroup) of level 2] that corresponds to $f_*(c)$ under the convering defined by the [modular function $\lambda$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function).

(The matrices of $\Gamma(2)$ act in $\mathbb{H}$ as Möbius transformations, and $\lambda:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a holomophic function such that $\lambda(\gamma(\tau))=\lambda(\tau)$ for any $\gamma\in\Gamma(2)$ and $\tau\in\mathbb{H}$. Furthermore, $\lambda:\mathbb{H}\to\hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus\{\infty,0,1\}$ is a covering space).

I don't understand how a matrix ($\gamma$) would be correspondent in any sense to a homotopy class ($f_*(c)$). Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Do you see how the matrix corresponds to a deck transformation? And can you imagine how a deck transformation of a universal cover corresponds to an element of the fundamental group of the base space?

Comment: Aside: A proof of Picard's theorem using the covering $\lambda \colon \mathbb{H} \to \hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus \{0,1,\infty\}$ was already classical in the eighties. I don't know if the proof in the paper differs much from that old one.

Comment: Lehner wrote a paper in the *American Mathematical Monthly* in 1969 describing the covering space proof. I don't think he was claiming any novelty for it even back then.

Comment: Thank you for the help, @DanielFischer, I didn't know the concept of deck transformation, but now that I know I can see the correspondence.